# How to convert ISO8601 in flutter

Tags: flutter, datetime-format, iso8601

How to convert below ISO8601 format into just month and day.

```
2022-08-29T10:33:49.283Z
```

to

```
29/8
```

Answer (score 8):

you can use [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl)

```
DateTime now = DateTime.parse('2022-08-29T10:33:49.283Z');
var formatter =  DateFormat('dd/MM');
var formatted = formatter.format(now);
print(formatted);
```

Answer (score 2):

U can use package [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl)

[Abr for the DateFormat class](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html)

```dart
final formatedDate = DateFormat('d/M').format(DateTime.now());
// ie: Prints 11/9(considering the date as today)
print(formatedDate);
```